# Script that watch elements and change text

Tags: jquery

I am using bootstrap editable to edit text property of photos. In default, it displays the text and if you click it, small window with editable text is opened. All I want to do is to create a script, which will replace the text with pencil icon. I wrote this:

```
$('#gallery').delegate('.editable-click', 'need_some_event' , function(){
    $(this).text();
    $(this).html('<i class="icon-pencil" ></i>');
}); //end delegate
```

The code i have:

```
<a class="edit editable editable-click" style="float:left; margin-right: 10px" href="#" rel="Photo_text_183" data-pk="183">some text descrtion of photo</a>
```

What i want to have after:

```
<a class="edit editable editable-click" style="float:left; margin-right: 10px" href="#" rel="Photo_text_183" data-pk="183"><i class="icon-pencil" ></i></a>
```

Problem is, that editable text is generated by another javascript. I basically need some event which will watch all .editable-click class elemnts and if they appear, remove the text with icon. Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could try to listen for `DOMNodeInserted`

```
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', function(){
if($(this).find('.editable-text').length > 0){
//do stuff 
}
});
```

here's a working fiddle as an example http://jsfiddle.net/wvVnQ/1/

Since, as mentioned below, this is being deprecated you might try this plugin: https://github.com/naugtur/insertionQuery

Comment: `DOMNodeInserted` won't work on older browsers, and soon won't work on newer browsers, as it has deprecated by W3C.

Comment: I did it with CSS in the end... .edit
{
 text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url("../img/glyphicons-halflings.png");
 width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
 background-position: 0 -72px;
}